# Simplfying JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, dayjs

I'm currently a web developer boot camp student and I am working on a project. I know there is a way to simplify this function but I can't seem to grasp it. What is the way to simplify this entire thing into a for loop so I don't have to do this to every element? I am calling a weather API and applying them to the HTMl. Also, I am using the querySelector as for some reason, JQuery doesn't want to allow me to use the $.

**HTML**

```
 <div class="row bottom">
   <div class="col"><span class="subtitle">-Temperature-</span></div>
   <div class="col">
     <div class="row" id="date1">Sun</div>
     <div class="row data" id="date1Temp"><b>-4&deg;</b></div>
   </div>
   <div class="col">
     <div class="row" id="date2">Mon</div>
     <div class="row data" id="date2Temp"><b>-5&deg;</b></div>
   </div>
   <div class="col">
     <div class="row" id="date3">Tue</div>
     <div class="row data" id="date3Temp"><b>-10&deg;</b></div>
   </div>
   <div class="col">
     <div class="row" id="date4">Wed</div>
     <div class="row data" id="date4Temp"><b>-4&deg;</b></div>
   </div>
   <div class="col">
     <div class="row" id="date5">Thu</div>
     <div class="row data" id="date5Temp"><b>-2&deg;</b></div>
   </div>
   <div class="col">
     <hr />
   </div>
 </div>
```

**JS**

```
let fiveDayWeather = function (weatherValue) {
  const date1 = document.querySelector("#date1");
  const date2 = document.querySelector("#date2");
  const date3 = document.querySelector("#date3");
  const date4 = document.querySelector("#date4");
  const date5 = document.querySelector("#date5");

  const date1Temp = document.querySelector("#date1Temp");
  const date2Temp = document.querySelector("#date2Temp");
  const date3Temp = document.querySelector("#date3Temp");
  const date4Temp = document.querySelector("#date4Temp");
  const date5Temp = document.querySelector("#date5Temp");

  let todaysMonth = dayjs().$M;
  let tomorrow = dayjs().$D + 1;
  let twoDaysAfter = dayjs().$D + 2;
  let threeDaysAfter = dayjs().$D + 3;
  let fourDaysAfter = dayjs().$D + 4;
  let fiveDaysAfter = dayjs().$D + 5;

  date1.innerText = `${todaysMonth}/${tomorrow}`;
  date1Temp.innerText = weatherValue.list[1].main.temp + "\u00B0 F";
  date2.innerText = `${todaysMonth}/${twoDaysAfter}`;
  date2Temp.innerText = weatherValue.list[2].main.temp + "\u00B0 F";
  date3.innerText = `${todaysMonth}/${threeDaysAfter}`;
  date3Temp.innerText = weatherValue.list[3].main.temp + "\u00B0 F";
  date4.innerText = `${todaysMonth}/${fourDaysAfter}`;
  date4Temp.innerText = weatherValue.list[4].main.temp + "\u00B0 F";
  date5.innerText = `${todaysMonth}/${fiveDaysAfter}`;
  date5Temp.innerText = weatherValue.list[5].main.temp + "\u00B0 F";
```

Comment: Could you please post your HTML too. You should be able to create a very simple loop to achieve your goal, without even the need for incremental `id`, which are an anti-pattern

Comment: Hint: `for( let i = 1; i <= 5; i++ ) { ...`

Comment: @Dai I'm aware of the for loop syntax but I just cannot find a way to apply it in this scenario unfortunately

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan I updated!

Comment: `const dateN = document.querySelector( '#date' + i.toString );`

Comment: @joonkidk thanks, I added an answer for you below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this should work:

```js
let fiveDayWeather = function (weatherValue) {

    let todaysMonth = dayjs().$M;

    for( let i = 1; i < 6; i++ ){

        document.querySelector( "#date" + i ).innerText = `${todaysMonth}/${ dayjs().$D + i }`;
        document.querySelector( "#date" + i + "Temp" ).innerText = weatherValue.list[i].main.temp + "\u00B0 F";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Here you go with some comments:

```
let fiveDayWeather = function (weatherValue) {
  let todaysMonth = dayjs().$M;
  [...Array(5).keys()] // generate array with indexes[ 0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
    .map((k) => `date${k + 1}`) // map each element to the format "date1" "date2" etc
    .forEach((id, index) => { // iterate the array with both the generated ids in the format you want and the index
      // get the elements
      const date = document.getElementById(id);
      const dateTemp = document.getElementById(id + "Temp");
      // set the day
      const day = dayjs().$D + index + 1;
      // edit html content
      date.innerText = `${todaysMonth}/${day}`;
      dateTemp.innerText = weatherValue.list[index + 1].main.temp + "\u00B0 F";
    });
};
```

Answer (score 0):

To DRY up your code you can amend your code to remove the incremental `id` attributes. Instead, you can use common `class` attributes to create common structures in your HTML which you can use DOM traversal methods, such as `closest()`, to find related content, something like this:

```js
const todaysMonth = dayjs().$M;

let fiveDayWeather = function(weatherValue) {
  document.querySelectorAll('.date').forEach((date, i) => {
    const temp = date.closest('.col').querySelector('.dateTemp');
    
    date.innerText = `${todaysMonth}/${dayjs().$D + (i + 1)}`;
    temp.innerText = weatherValue.list[i + 1].main.temp + "\u00B0 F";    
  });
}

// dummy data set:
fiveDayWeather({
  list: [
    { main: { temp: 0 } },
    { main: { temp: 1 } },
    { main: { temp: 2 } },
    { main: { temp: 3 } },
    { main: { temp: 4 } },
    { main: { temp: 5 } },
    { main: { temp: 6 } }
  ]
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/dayjs/1.11.6/dayjs.min.js" integrity="sha512-hcV6DX35BKgiTiWYrJgPbu3FxS6CsCjKgmrsPRpUPkXWbvPiKxvSVSdhWX0yXcPctOI2FJ4WP6N1zH+17B/sAA==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
<div class="row bottom">
  <div class="col"><span class="subtitle">-Temperature-</span></div>
  <div class="col">
    <div class="row date">Sun</div>
    <div class="row data dateTemp"><b>-4&deg;</b></div>
  </div>
  <div class="col">
    <div class="row date">Mon</div>
    <div class="row data dateTemp"><b>-5&deg;</b></div>
  </div>
  <div class="col">
    <div class="row date">Tue</div>
    <div class="row data dateTemp"><b>-10&deg;</b></div>
  </div>
  <div class="col">
    <div class="row date">Wed</div>
    <div class="row data dateTemp"><b>-4&deg;</b></div>
  </div>
  <div class="col">
    <div class="row date">Thu</div>
    <div class="row data dateTemp"><b>-2&deg;</b></div>
  </div>
  <div class="col">
    <hr />
  </div>
</div>
```